# android- Unable to get text from textview

Tags: java, android, textview

i need to read the text from textview1 but the text is always not the same as "-shutdown"
but on the textview is displayed the text "-shutdown"

Or is there any other ways to read directly text from bo.toString() withut write it in a textview??

Thanks.

My activity class:

```
  package com.example.androrem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
 import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.ContentResolver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.res.AssetManager;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException;
 import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class ReadSMS extends Activity {




  private static final int duration = 0;


 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_sms);   
  doButton1();


  }

  private void readData(){
  new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          String path ="http://androidremoter.altervista.org/zero/test.txt";
          URL u = null;
          try {
              u = new URL(path);
              HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
              c.setRequestMethod("GET");
              c.connect();
              InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
              final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
              bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.            

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                      text.setText(bo.toString()); //the textview display "-shutdown" 
                      String input = text.getText().toString();//get text from textview
                      String com1 = "-shutdown";
                      if(input==com1)//always show not work
                      {
                          TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                          text2.setText("work"); 
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                          text2.setText("not work");
                      }
                      try {

                          bo.close();

                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
              });

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }
  }.start();

 }




 private void doButton1()
 {

  Button gettext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test1);
  gettext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
  // Do something in response to button click
  readData();
 }
    }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare two Strings like that. You are comparing the objects rather than the contents. Do this instead:

```
if (input.trim().equals(com1)) {
    ...
```

Comment: already tried dont work...

Comment: with "don't work" you mean your app is crashing or what? @user3642538

Comment: Take a look at my edit and see if that works. I have a feeling you had some trailing white space.

Comment: it mean the textview2 is saying "dont work"

Comment: You are welcome. Go ahead and mark as answered if your issue is resolved.